# Генерация точек, записей!

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Суть в том что сейчас этот "мозг" сделан с помощью картинки и указания точного позиционирования к точкам.

В реализации эти точки будут добавляться. И хотелось бы сделать генерацию(отрисовку) линий и точек. Никогда не сталкивался с этим. Может кто знает в каком направлении думать. Может кто видел подобное.

Comment: Может быть лучше всего это реализовать с помощью SVG

Comment: Можна через (Canvas)[http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp]

Comment: @vp_arth да, svg безусловно.
Вопрос в том как реализовать генерацию точек. К примеру есть 6 точек который генерируют основную структуру. Но потом добавится еще 6 точек. И нужно добавить линии которые связывают "мозг" и точка.

Comment: Как точки, так и связи между ними нужно хранить, потому что граф "мозга" не является полным(иначе можно было бы сгенерировать)

Comment: От места новой точки сделать радиус обнаружения других,если найдено то линия или добавить кастомный атрибут и в нем указывать другие точки потом их соединять .